# Read package.json from TFS agent Build using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm trying to get version field from package.json file of my .net core project, PowerShell Task is excuted after excuting Get Resource Task, i used this script powershell witch work perfectly in my local my machine :

```
$package_json_path  = (Get-Childitem -LiteralPath  .\  -Include package.json -Recurse  | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\wwwroot\*"} | Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\node_modules\*"} | Where {$_.FullName -like "*\release\*"} | Select-Object -First 1).fullName
Write-Host ("$package_json_path")
$SemverVersion = (Get-Content  -Path $package_json_path) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty "version"
```

But in TFS it shows this error :

```
Get-Content : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Path », car il a la valeur Null.
Le processus s'est achevé avec le code de sortie 0. 1 erreur(s) écrite(s) dans le flux d'erreurs.
```

I guess it's a problem of PowerShell version installed in my TFS

Comment: I'd guess the working directory is not what you expect and it's not finding the `package.json` because of it.

Comment: I have 3 agents in TFS, when queue a build, i can't choose a specefic agent, so can't replace the .\  with the gent temp folder, i can change it with D:\ , but if it work it will a so long time because it will search in all agent files, i think i have to make a path pattern using asterisc, but i give me an error.

Comment: Use the `$env:AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY` or one of the other agent environment variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch

Comment: `$env:AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY` is not a predefined variable

Comment: Straight from the docs: Variable Name
Environment Variable Name Scope Notes
Agent.BuildDirectory

AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY

Agent 
The local path on the agent where all folders for a given build definition are created. For example: c:\agent\_work\1

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i try it, and it give the same error as shown in the post

Comment: @BoubakrEchieb If you have 3 agents in TFS, you could  add a user Capability to that specific build agent then in the build definition you put that capability as a demand (General tab). This will send build to a specific build agent. This could help you trouble shooting if it's related to single build agent and the version of powershell. Moreover, suggest you translate your error message to English, this will get more attention from others.

Comment: What's build configuration you set in the build? Your script is trying to find the package.json file from a release folder. Did you see the release folder generated during the build? Can you share your detailed build logs?